# Benchmarking MXD vs MSD performance?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, performance, mxd, msd

Has anyone seen any publically available benchmarks of MSDs vs MXDs?

If we ignore the fact that as part of the MSD publishing process, we run it through some validators with the [map service publishing toolbar](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sq00000018000000.htm), in terms of rendering, **how much quicker do MSDs render?**

And can we break this down further.  I know MSDs are faster to render, **but are there particular situations where they will render a lot faster?**

- Basic vector layers Vs Imagery
- Simple symbols vs Multi-layer symbols
- Lots of layers Vs Lots of features, etc

I thought there would be something in the [Capacity Planning Tool wiki](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Software_Performance#ArcGIS_Server_Optimized_Map_Service_Document_.28MSD.29), but could not spot anything that goes into detail on what circumstances the MSD outshines the MXD.

I want to see some stats and graphs on MXDs vs MSDs.

*As a sidenote, at 10.1 we only have the option of MSDs.*

Answer (score 2):

*This answer is a working progress.*
I aim to do some of my own benchmarks with some Esri sample datasets and also gather stats from external sources.

From the [GISWorx link](http://www.gisworx.ae/about/downloads/presentation_downloads/Gistec-Sandeep%20Kuniel%20&%20Sumoj%20John-%20ArcGIS%20Server%20Performance%20and%20Scalability.pdf):
[image]

From the [Esri UK link:](http://www.esriuk.com/developerhub090210/presentations/DeveloperHub_Performance.pdf) *(Although this relates to the optimisers pointing out potential problems with choices in authoring stage  e.g. use of maplex)*
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this...
[Performance considerations 10](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/enterprisegis/10.0/services_performance)
And...
a 9.3.1 thread discussing [arcserver performance](http://forums.esri.com/thread.asp?c=158&f=2276&t=280758)

[ESRI UK developer hub](http://www.esriuk.com/developerhub090210/presentations/DeveloperHub_Performance.pdf)

[SOE discussion Blog](http://viswaug.wordpress.com/2009/09/29/black-magic-behind-the-msd-map-services/)

[Wiki.GIS.com](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Software_Performance_28th_Edition_%28Fall_2010%29#ArcGIS_Server_Optimized_Map_Service_Document_.28MSD.29)

[Gisworx](http://www.gisworx.ae/about/downloads/presentation_downloads/Gistec-Sandeep%20Kuniel%20&%20Sumoj%20John-%20ArcGIS%20Server%20Performance%20and%20Scalability.pdf)

Comment: I like 1st link, although id still like to see more in depth summaries of MXDs vs MSDs.   It seems to be more specific around how they scale.

Comment: Yes. You did see the right column where you can download benchmark tools?  The page is for 10 but the downloads all say 9.3.1 not sure if they run for 10 (I would assume so). It would be nice if there were more of them.

Comment: Ill have a look at these tools.  However, its the RESULTS of running these kind of tools against MXDs/MSDs in a variety of situations that im looking for.

Comment: I see. This would be a good question for the ESRI UC questions wiki.  http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/518/what-questions-should-attendees-of-the-esri-uc-be-asking  and even better to hit up esri while they are at UC alreeady in the answer questions mode... :)